# How to install vstest.console.exe offline

Tags: visual-studio, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

I am supposed to do an offline installation of `vstest.console.exe` in the folder path as follows: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow`

I have tried using offline packages such as `vs_testagent.exe` and `vs_testcontroller.exe` according to the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio. However, these packages do not contain `vstest.console.exe`.

I am also unable to do a full installation of VS2017 due to space issues. Do anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It's available when install Visual Studio Build Tools' [component Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 7):

Download the nuget package: [Microsoft.TestPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform/), rename it a zip file. Open the zip file, you will find all you need from this folder: `.\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform`,  including `vstest.console.exe`, `testhost.**.exe`, `QTAgent.exe`, `datacollector.exe`.

If you added the nuget package to project, it just downloads the package to `packages` folder and won't complie to `bin`, so you have to add a `Post-Build` event to copy files to `bin` folder from the `packages` folder.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for ["Build Tools for Visual Studio"](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=build%20tools%20for%20visual%20studio) (Microsoft login required). It will give you an installer "vs_BuildTools.exe", which will install by default the build tools in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools

(by default)

Two versions of vstest console were installed when I ran it:

1. ...\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe
2. ...\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe

I do not know why, nor how they are different. I use the first one.

Comment: The first one is Test Platform v1 (TPv1), whereas the second is Test Platform v2 (TPv2). See https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/contribute.md#running-tests-with-tpv2-using-test-explorer (permalink: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/206f9377959ca17bf12ba24150bab17bcec8a41a/docs/contribute.md#running-tests-with-tpv2-using-test-explorer)

Comment: The web-installer of `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022` doesn't install `vstest.console.exe` or anything similar

Answer (score 2):

Download the Visual Studio Build Tools installer from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=build%20tools%20for%20visual%20studio

Run the installer, click the tab Individual components and select **Testing tool core features - Build Tools**

[image]

After installation the vstest.console.exe is located in folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

Answer (score 0):

I used the chocolatey package `visualstudio2019testagent` to install VS 2019 Test Agent.

Not sure if this would help someone in the future.